# Select records with multiple row criteria in sql server

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a table like this

```
ID          Day  Start End
----------- ---- ----- -----
1           M    7:30  9:30
2           T    7:30  11:30
3           T    12:30 14:30
```

And another table like this

```
Day  Start End
---- ----- -----
M    8:30  11:30
T    8:30  10:30
```

I want to select all records from the first table that is based from the second table.

Example Result :

```
ID          Day  Start End  
----------- ---- ----- -----
1           M    7:30  9:30 
2           T    7:30  11:30
```

The result is like that because the first 2 records in the 1st table matched the criterion from the second table. The 1st and 2nd row has the same day and the time clashed with the other one.

Comment: What're the data types of `Start` and `End`?

Comment: And sql-server version is?

Comment: Do not quote the SQL schema. Use code formatting.

Comment: @delbertwah are you only getting the first record of the day? because on your table 1 Tuesday you have two records and only get the first one in your output.

Comment: use where exists.Ok sorry,Guess i didn't read the last para.Can you through few more sample data where time don't clash and output will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This join will work:

```
select * 
from t1
join t2 on t1.day = t2.day and t1.end >= t2.start and t1.start <= t2.end
```

If time columns are `varchars` you need to cast to `time`:

```
select * 
from t1
join t2 on t1.day = t2.day and 
           cast(t1.end as time) >= cast(t2.start as time) and 
           cast(t1.start as time) <= cast(t2.end as time)
```