# Need to join 3 tables, depending on 3rd table latest salaryDate column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have three tables and I'd like to join them based on last month `salaryDate` column.

- `tbl1` (empID, Name, ctNo)
- `tbl2` (salID, empID, salry)
- `tbl3` (histryID, salDate, empID, salID)

Hope you get back soon guys

Comment: I joined 3 tables. But it show all salaryDate column. For eg: Each emp get salary every month, I need to show lastmonth salary date,salary,empID,Name only for all employees

Comment: Join 3 with 1 on salid join 3 with 2 on empId last where datepart(mm,saldate) >=Datepart(mm,Getdate()) -1

Comment: It display employees all last month salary. I expect each and every employees latest getting salaryDate only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done with `APPLY`:

```
select t1.empid, t1.name, oa.saldate, t2.salary
from tbl1 t1
cross apply(select top 1 * from tbl3 
            where empid = t1.empid
            order by saldate desc)oa
join tbl2 t2 on oa.empid = t2.empid AND oa.salid = t2.salid
```

Comment: I used your Query it Display all SalaryDate. My requirement is show only lastmonth salaryDate for all employees.

Comment: @Parameswaran, I have checked and what?

Comment: I wrote this query .  select tbl_1.emp_Id,Name,salary,salary_Date,tbl_3.salary_Id from tbl_1 inner join tbl_2 on tbl_1.emp_Id=tbl_2.emp_Id inner join tbl_3 on tbl_2.salary_Id=tbl_3.salary_Id .  It display all the salary date

Comment: @Parameswaran, don't you want last taken salary? For emp 1, 3 you take earliest salary, for 2 latest? My query will return each employee with latest salary.

Comment: @Parameswaran, I think I got you: try `order by history_Id` instead of `order by saldate desc`

Comment: @Parameswaran, provide http://sqlfiddle.com/ data of 3 tables or edit your question. Look here how to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470909/select-records-with-multiple-row-criteria-in-sql-server/33470943#33470943

Comment: Thank You very much my FRIEND  Giorgi Nakeuri. I got answer.. Thank you.. When use order by history_Id , Then I got it...

Comment: @Parameswaran, `To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.` http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: @ Giorgi Nakeuri Hi, I got answer. We need to use Partition by or self join. Not like to use cross apply. That is my task. Can you change it?                   
select emp_Id,salary_Date from (select emp_Id,salary_Date,rank() over(partition by emp_Id 
order by history_Id desc)as 'ranking' from  tbl_EmployeeSalaryHistory) testing where ranking<2

Comment: @Parameswaran, that is another question. I can not sit here answering endless questions. Better ask a new question providing sample data. And I will look at that question.

Comment: I have asked one more Question in forum. Please look at that and solve.